# how to use tooltip in angular 4 with bootstrap tether jquery installed from npm?

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

Is there any way to use tooltip features from bootstrap 4?

We've already installed bootstrap 4, tether, and jquery using npm install,

and in the documentation we have to write jquery code in javascript,

```
$(function () [
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

and add this code in html,

```
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top"
```

We've tried to add the html code but not working, obviously we have to write the jquery code, but can we write jquery syntax in angular 4 which using typescript?
then where to put the syntax in angular 4?

Comment: Add ng-bootstrap and they have component for all. You can directly use them

Comment: Jquery and Angular don't play well together. Perhaps you can use ng-boostrap or another library like [ngx-popover](https://github.com/pleerock/ngx-popover)

Comment: Yup, jQuery and all is not great with Angular. For native tooltip implementation check https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

Answer (score 4):

Add jquery, tether and bootstrap scripts to `angular-cli.json`

```
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
],
```

Then go to your desired component. and type `declare var $: any;`.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// this line will allow you to use jQuery
declare var $: any;

@Component({
  ...
})
```

Put your content inside `ngOnInit() { /* Content here. */ }`.

```
ngOnInit() {
  $(() => {
    // Testing jQuery
    console.log('hello there!');
  });
}
```

I prefer not to use jQuery in angular, its not a good practice, try searching for tooltips build on top of angular or use `Renderer2` 
https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2 or build your own directive for this, Angular Material2 has tooltip component that you might want to use, very easy to implement in typescript.

https://material.angular.io/components/tooltip/overview

For complete docs.

https://github.com/angular/material2

Answer (score 2):

I did it by creating a directive.

```typescript
import { Directive, OnInit, Inject, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { JQUERY_TOKEN } from './jquery.service';

@Directive({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'
})
export class TooltipDirective implements OnInit {
    private el: HTMLElement;

    constructor(elRef: ElementRef, @Inject(JQUERY_TOKEN) private $: JQueryStatic) {
        this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.$(this.el).tooltip();
    }
}
```

This is my `jquery.service` file mentioned in the `import` statement

```typescript
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const JQUERY_TOKEN = new InjectionToken<JQueryStatic>('jQuery');
```

Then add to the module

```typescript
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { TooltipDirective } from './tooltip.directive';
import { JQUERY_TOKEN } from './jquery.service';

export let jQuery: JQueryStatic = window['jQuery'];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        // ...
    ],
    declarations: [
        TooltipDirective
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: JQUERY_TOKEN, useValue: jQuery }
    ]
})
export class MyModule {}
```

Then simply add it to the component where you need it. For example, in my `app.component.ts` file, all I had to do is add this one line at the top to get it to work with the template:

```typescript
import { TooltipDirective } from './tooltip.directive';
```